# I am getting the wrong result for all ages above 5. I cannot use switch statements

Tags: php, if-statement

This is the code in question. It seems right to me but it for all ages above 5, it outputs "You can go to preschool"

```
<?php

$age = 13;

if ($age < 3) {
    echo "You are too young for school";
} elseif ($age = 3 or $age = 4) {
    echo "You can go to preschool";
} elseif ($age >= 5 and $age < 12) {
    echo "You can go to primary school";
} elseif ($age >= 12 and $age < 18) {
    echo "You can go to high school";
} else {
    echo "You do not have to go to school";
}

?>
```

Comment: Typo: `elseif ($age = 3 or $age = 4)` you need to use `==` for comparison, not `=`.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the lower bounds in your comparisons, since the previous `if` statements already ensure that you're at least there.

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` and `===` are for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You need "==" for compare (just values) `$var == $var2` or use "===" for more strict comparation (type and value).

The difference is this

```
<?php
$var = 1;
$var2 = "1;

echo $var == $var2; //Return 1 (true). Value comparation.
echo $var === $var2; //Return 0 (false). Value and type comparation [int not equal string, but still being 1 == "1"]
```

So your code should be like this (if age ever will be a int, else use "=="):

```
<?php

$age = 13;

if ($age < 3) {
    echo "You are too young for school";
} elseif ($age === 3 or $age === 4) {
    echo "You can go to preschool";
} elseif ($age >= 5 and $age < 12) {
    echo "You can go to primary school";
} elseif ($age >= 12 and $age < 18) {
    echo "You can go to high school";
} else {
    echo "You do not have to go to school";
}

?>
```

The difference between the loosely == equal operator and the strict === identical operator is exactly explained in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison).